# Powershell: coerce or cast to type as named in a string variable

Tags: powershell, types, casting, type-coercion

I am trying to use the method outlined [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31895.adding-type-accelerators-in-the-powershell-5-0-april-2015-preview.aspx) to create a number of custom data types, and rather than having a line for each I would like to define a hash table of the names and types like this

```
$pxAccelerators = @{
   pxListObject = '[System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]'
   pxListString = '[System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]'
   pxOrderedDictionary = '[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]'
}
```

Then I could use something like this

```
$typeAccelerators = [PowerShell].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")
foreach ($key in $pxAccelerators.Keys) {
    $name = $key
    $type = $pxAccelerators.$key
    $typeAccelerators::Add($key,$type)
}
```

to loop through the hash table and add each one.
However, the issue of course is that `$type` isn't an actual type, it's a string. And `$typeAccelerators::Add($key,$type)` needs a string and an actual type. So basically I need to coerce a string like `'[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]'` to the actual type. I have found plenty of references to casting or coercing from one data type to another, but I can't seem to find any reference to how to convert a string to a type as defined BY the string.
I have tried all these stabs in the dark

```
([System.Type]'[System.Collections.ArrayList]')::new()
[System.Type]'[System.Collections.ArrayList]'
[System.Type]'[System.Collections.ArrayList]' -as [System.Type]
'[System.Collections.ArrayList]' -as ([PowerShell].Assembly.GetType('[System.Collections.ArrayList]')
```

to no avail.
`$type = ([PowerShell].Assembly.GetType('[System.Collections.ArrayList]'))` seems to work, in that it doesn't throw an exception. But `$type.GetType()` does throw `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`.
Interestingly, auto completion with `[PowerShell].Assembly.GetType('[System.Collections.ArrayList]').` shows properties like `BaseType` and `FullName` are available, suggesting that I have actually produced a type, but using `.GetType()` on the result throws an exception.
I tried

```
$pxAccelerators = @{
   pxListObject = 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]'
   pxListString = 'System.Collections.Generic.List[String]'
   pxOrderedDictionary = 'System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary'
}
$typeAccelerators = [PowerShell].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")
foreach ($key in $pxAccelerators.Keys) {
    $name = $key
    $type = [PowerShell].Assembly.GetType($pxAccelerators.$key)
    $typeAccelerators::Add($key,$type)
}

[PSObject].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")::Get
```

and the accelerators are being added, but the type to be acclerated is not there, suggesting that the `GetType()` line is not actually producing a type.

Lastly, I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) which seems to be getting closer. But I can't seem to rock how to access the method without starting from some sort of type already, and `[System.Type].GetType('System.Int32')` is throwing, so that seems to be a dead end.

Am I trying to do something impossible? Or just missing the proper mechanism?

Comment: The name of a type does not include `[]`, that's just the PowerShell way of writing type literals. `Type.GetType` throws because it's not an instance method; `[Type]::GetType('System.Int32')` works just fine. Even with that `List[String]` will not work because that's not how a type is named in .NET (it would be ``List`1`` and then instantiated with `String`); the cheapest way of doing it would be `Invoke-Expression '[System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]'`, assuming you can be certain your strings never come from user input (as `iex` executes arbitrary code).

Comment: Aha! I hadn't even thought of invoke-Expression, but that's because I know it's generally unsafe and best avoided. But here the values are hard coded, so short of someone actually modifying my script, it should be safe.

Comment: All that said -- why not just use `[System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]].ToString()`? Some experimentation shows `[Type]::GetType()` will parse the resulting string correctly back into a type, that is, `[Type]::GetType([System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]].ToString()) -eq [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]` is `true` (but I'm testing that with PS 7.1, so that may be a recent innovation -- I don't think it used to process generics correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `-as [type]` will do

The `-as` operator gladly takes a type name as it's right-hand side operand.

Change the values of your dictionary to contain just a valid type name, and it becomes as easy as:

```
$pxAccelerators = @{
   pxListObject = 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]'
   pxListString = 'System.Collections.Generic.List[String]'
   pxOrderedDictionary = 'System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary'
}

$typeAccelerators = [PowerShell].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")
foreach ($acc in $pxAccelerators.GetEnumerator()) {
    $name = $acc.Key
    $type = $acc.Value -as [type]
    $typeAccelerators::Add($name,$type)
}
```

Result:

```
PS ~> [pxOrderedDictionary] -is [type]
True
PS ~> [pxOrderedDictionary].FullName
System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
```

Comment: It's interesting that `'[System.Collections.ArrayList]' -as [Type]` didn't work, but also didn't throw any kind of error. Lose the brackets in the string and it works, but with no error that's a hard one to figure out.

Comment: `-as` _never_ throws, by design. `[type]'System.Collections.ArrayList'` or `'System.Collections.ArrayList' -as [type]` would've worked

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, **your only problem was that you accidentally enclosed your type-name *string values* in `[...]`** (e.g, `'[System.Collections.ArrayList]'`), whereas this notation only works in - unquoted - *type literals*:

- **`[...]`** is a ***PowerShell-specific* notation** for ***type literals*** (e.g., `[System.DateTime]`); .NET methods do *not* recognize this, although the string  *inside* `[...]` (e.g., `System.DateTime`) uses a *superset* of the language-agnostic notation recognized by .NET methods such as [`System.Type.GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Type.GetType) - see bottom section.

In your case, you don't even need *explicit* conversion of your type-name strings to `[type]` objects, because PowerShell *implicitly* performs this conversion when you call the `::Add()` method. Therefore, the following is sufficient:

```bash
@{
   pxListObject = 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]'
   pxListString = 'System.Collections.Generic.List[String]'
   pxOrderedDictionary = 'System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary'
}.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {

  # Calling ::Add() implicitly converts the type-name *string* to the required
  # [type] instance. 
  [powershell].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators')::Add(
    $_.Key,
    $_.Value
  )

}
```

Of course, you could have *directly* used type *literals* as your hashtable values:

```bash
# Note the use of [...] values (type literals) instead of strings.
@{
   pxListObject = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]
   pxListString = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]
   pxOrderedDictionary = [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]
}.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
  [powershell].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators')::Add(
    $_.Key,
    $_.Value
  )

}
```

**Caveat**:

- Type `System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators` is *non-public* (hence the need to access it via *reflection*), and relying on non-public APIs is problematic.
- The alternative, available in PowerShell v5+, is to use the **[`using namespace` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Using)** so you don't have to specify a *full* type name (see the bottom section for an example) - though note that it invariably makes *all* types in the specified namespace available by simple name (no namespace part).

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$type = [PowerShell].Assembly.GetType('[System.Collections.ArrayList]')` seems to work, in that it doesn't throw an exception.

- As stated, the outer `[...]` are *not* a part of the type name; however, removing them wouldn't be enough here, because the specified type isn't part of the same assembly as `[PowerShell]`.
- Generally, [`System.Type.GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Type.GetType) quietly returns `$null` if the specified type cannot be found; e.g.: `[PowerShell].Assembly.GetType('DefinitelyNoSuchType')`

> `[PowerShell].Assembly.GetType($pxAccelerators.$key)`
> suggesting that the GetType() line is not actually producing a type.

The reason is that `System.Type.GetType()` doesn't recognize *closed* generic types such as `System.Collections.Generic.List[String]`, because the underlying notation only supports *open* ones (such as `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ``); the former notation is a *PowerShell-specific extension* to the notation - see the bottom section.

---

#### Converting type *names* stored in *strings* - *without* the enclosing `[...]` - to [`System.Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Type) (`[type]`) objects:

Cast to `[type]`:

```bash
# Same as: [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]; case does not matter.
[type] 'System.Collections.Generic.List[string]'
```

- Casting to `[type]` does *more* than calling [`System.Type.GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Type.GetType), because PowerShell's type-name strings support a *superset* of the latter's notation - see the bottom section.
- The above will cause a statement-terminating error (exception) if no such type is found (or the syntax is incorrect); note that only types among *currently loaded* assemblies are found.
- Alternatively, you can use `'System.Collections.Generic.List[string]' -as [type]`, as shown in [Mathias R. Jessen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65090568/45375), which quietly returns `$null` if conversion to a type isn't possible; see [`-as`, the conditional type conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators).

Note that both `-as` and `-is` also accept type-name strings *as their RHS*; e.g. `42 -is 'int'` or `'42' -as 'int'`

Also, the [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object) cmdlet accepts *strings* as its `-TypeName` argument, so again the type-*literal*-enclosing `[...]` must *not* be used; e.g.,
`New-Object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding`

---

#### PowerShell's type-literal and type-name notation:

- A PowerShell **type *literal*** (e.g., `[System.DateTime]`) is a **type *name* enclosed in `[...]`**, but the `[` and `]` are *not* part of the name.

  - Type literals are themselves instance of [`System.Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Type) (`[type]`), or, more accurately, instances of the non-public [`System.RuntimeType`] type, which *derives* from `System.Reflection.TypeInfo`, which in turn derives from `System.Type`.
- **Type-name *strings* can generally also be used where type literals (objects representing *types*) are accepted**, with PowerShell converting to `[type]` *implicitly*, notably during parameter binding and on the RHS of `-as`, the [conditional type-conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators) and `-is`, the [type(-inheritance) / interface test operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators).

**PowerShell implements a *superset* of the language-agnostic type-name notation used by .NET**:

- The **language-agnostic .NET notation**, as used by [`System.Type.GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Type.GetType), for instance, is documented in [Specifying fully qualified type names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/specifying-fully-qualified-type-names), and notably requires and includes:

  - **Type names must be (at least) *namespace-qualified* names** (e.g., `System.Int32` rather than just `Int32`), and must be specified case-*exactly* by default; however, an overload with an `ignoreCase` parameter is available; names can optionally be *assembly-qualified* so as to also indicate the type's assembly of origin.
  - **Suffix `` `<num> `` indicates the arity of generic types**, i.e, the number (`<num>`) of type arguments the generic type requires (e.g, `` `1 `` for a type with *one* generic type parameter, such as [`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1)).

    - Using *only* a generic type's arity returns a generic *type definition*.

      - A generic type definition cannot be directly instantiated; instead, you must call the [`.MakeGenericType()` instance method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Type.MakeGenericType) on the type object returned and pass (closed) type arguments for all generic type parameters, which then returns a *closed* [constructed] generic type, i.e. a concrete instantiation of the generic type definition from which instances can be constructed.
  - If you **optionally follow the generic arity specifier with a list of *type arguments*** to bind all *type parameters* defined by the generic type, a *constructed* generic type is directly returned; if all type arguments are closed themselves, transitively, i.e. have no unbound type parameters, if applicable, the type returned is a *closed* [constructed] type, which can directly be instantiated (its constructors can be called). The list of type arguments has the form `[<type>]` or, for multiple type arguments,  `[<type>, ...]`; `<type>` references are subject to the same rules as the enclosing generic type's name, and *may* additionally be enclosed in `[...]` *individually*.

    - For instance, the following two type literals, which construct a closed [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary-2) type (to use C# notation for a change) with `[string]` keys and `[int]` values, are therefore equivalent:

      - `` System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String, System.Int32] ``
      - `` System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String], [System.Int32]] ``
  - **Suffixes `[]` / `[,]` indicate a single-dimensional / two-dimensional *array***; e.g., `System.Int32[]`.
  - **`+` is used to separate *nested* types** from their containing class; e.g., `System.Environment+SpecialFolder`.
- The **PowerShell-specific *extensions*** are:

  - **Name matching is *invariably* case-*insensitive***; e.g., type  [`System.Text.UTF8Encoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.UTF8Encoding) can be targeted as `[system.text.utf8encoding]`.
  - **You may *omit* the `System.` component** of the full name; e.g., `[Text.UTF8Encoding]`
  - **You may use the names of PowerShell's [*type accelerators*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Accelerators)**; e.g., `[regex]`.
  - In **PowerShell v5+** you can also use the **[`using namespace` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Using)** so you don't have to specify a *full* type name:

    - E.g., placing `using namespace System.Text` at the top of a script or script module then allows you to refer to `[System.Text.UTF8Encoding]` as just `[UTF8Encoding]`
  - **When you pass a list of generic type arguments, you may *omit* the type's arity specifier**.

    - For instance, the following two type literals, which construct a closed [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary-2) type with `[string]` keys and `[int]` values, are therefore equivalent:

      - `[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string, int]]`
      - `` [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[string, int]] ``

Answer (score 0):

### Example Use of Script Block to Solve the Problem

Maybe I was doing something wrong, but for some reason this dynamically built string didn't seem to like any of the official answers here:

```
[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[System.Action[string, object]]]::new()
```

I gave up and did the following, perhaps this will be useful to someone else:

```
. ([ScriptBlock]::Create(@"
param(`$MyClass)
`$MyClass | Add-Member -NotePropertyName '$HashSetName' -NotePropertyValue ([System.Collections.Generic.HashSet$EventDef]::new())
"@)) -MyClass $this
```