# how to assign MaxValue and MinValue to a variable in powershell

Tags: powershell

I tried these assignment statements below but none of them works.

```
$max_value = Integer.MaxValue

$max_value = Int32.MaxValue

$max_value = int.MaxValue
```

Answer (score 1):

[Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) provided the crucial pointer:

```bash
# Equivalent of the following C# code: int.MaxValue or System.Int32.MaxValue
[int]::MaxValue
```

- **`[int]`** is a **PowerShell *type literal*** that refers to .NET's [`System.Int32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Int32) type, i.e. a signed, 32-bit integer.
- **[`::`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#static-member-operator-)** is PowerShell's operator for **accessing *static* type members** (whereas [`.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-) is used for *instance* members, as in C#).

Aside from requiring that literal type names be enclosed in `[...]`, PowerShell's type literals have some non-obvious features:

- Unlike in C#, **case does *not* matter in PowerShell type literals**. E.g., `[system.io.fileinfo]` can be used to refer to the [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) type.
- Analogous to C# providing short names for frequently used types - such as `int` for `System.Int32` and `string` for `System.String` - PowerShell defines a range of **short type names called *type accelerators***, listed in the conceptual [about_Type_Accelerators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Accelerators) help topic.

  - Case in point: as in C#, `[int]` refers to `System.Int32`, which you may therefore also reference as `[System.Int32]`.
  - You can invoke `.FullName` on any given type literal to see the target type's full (namespace-qualified) name; e.g, `[int].FullName` returns string `System.Int32`. This relies on the fact that any type literal is itself an instance of the [`System.Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Type) type.
- Irrespective of type accelerators, **you always have the option of omitting the `System.` component of a type's name**, so that you may refer to [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable) as just `[Linq.Enumerable]` instead of having to spell out `[System.Linq.Enumerable]`, for instance.
- In PowerShell version 5 and above (including PowerShell (Core) 7+), you may use a **[`using namespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Using#namespace-syntax) statement**, which, analogous to C#'s `using` statement, **allows you to refer to the types in the specified namespace by their *mere name***; e.g.:

  ```bash
   # Important:
   #  * Must be at the *start* of a file.
   #  * The System. part may NOT be omitted in this case.
   using namespace System.Linq

   [Enumerable]  # Short for: [System.Linq.Enumerable]
  ```

To **learn more** about type literals in PowerShell, including how to specify *generic* types, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65093924/45375).