# How to get PowerShell to export error message to CSV?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, active-directory, export-to-csv

I'm trying to modify a PowerShell script to append errors in a CSV file. A former coworker had created a script to take computer names from a txt file, go through Active Directory, and create a CSV file (creates an Excel file, if that helps) with the resulting divisions and canonical names. The CSV file has three columns; "Name", which holds the names directly from the txt file; "Division" (pulled from "name" in AD) which holds the name of the division/department the system is part of; and "CanonicalName", which holds the full Canonical Name of each system as displayed in AD. Sometimes a computer will not have an entry in AD, and it will throw an error message into the host and that system will be missing from the CSV file. Below is the modified script, and for privacy reasons the file path will read "File Path" and show no actual file path.

Here's what I currently have:

```
$ComputerList = Get-Content "File Path"
$Date = Get-Date -Format dd-MM-yyyy

foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList)
{
    if (@(Get-ADComputer $Computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count) #Check if computer exists in AD
    {
       Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computer -Properties * | Select Name, @{n='Division'; e={([string]$_.o)}}, CanonicalName |
       Export-Csv "File Path" -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
    else #Annotate if computer does not exist in AD
    {
       $NoComputer = [PSCustomObject]
       @{
          Name = $Computer
          Division = "Object Not Found"
          CanonicalName = " "
       }
       
       $CSVData = $NoComputer | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
       $CSVData | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
       Export-Csv "File Path" -NoTypeInformation -Append #<-- Error happens on this line, according to host
    }
}
```

When running the script as shown above, it still throws the error message into the host, along with two columns for each missing systems that appear as follows (actual computer name not shown for privacy reasons):

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                          
Name                           ComputerName                                                                                                                  
CanonicalName                                                                                                                                            
Division                       Object Not Found
```

It also throws the following error message in the host:

```
Export-Csv : Cannot append CSV content to the following file: File Path\Computer 
Identity List.csv. The appended object does not have a property that corresponds to the following column: Name. To continue with mismatched properties, add the -Force parameter, and then 
retry the command.
At File Path.ps1:36 char:8
+        Export-Csv File Path
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Name:String) [Export-Csv], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotAppendCsvWithMismatchedPropertyNames,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

It then leaves out that system in the CSV file, when I want it to list the system and append that it couldn't find the system with "Object Not Found" in the "Division" column of the CSV file. I tried doing -Force, but it just creates a blank row instead. Based on what I've looked up, this should be working, but clearly I'm missing something. What do I need to change in order to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your logic to use a `try / catch` instead of an `if / else`, `Get-ADComputer` will not respect the the `-ErrorAction` unless you pipe input to it. You will also benefit your script's performance by querying only those attributes of interest (`o` and `canonicalName`) instead of all attributes (`*`), and also by constructing your output before exporting it instead of appending to it.

You also have a typo in your `[PSCustomObject]` line, the hashtable (`@{ ... }`) must be in the same line as the type accelerator and this is causing the *property mismatch* error when you export them to Csv, the variable `$NoComputer` is getting assigned the type of `PSObject` instead of your actual object.

```bash
$result = foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList) {
    $object = [pscustomobject]@{
        Computer      = $computer
        Division      = ''
        CanonicalName = ''
    }

    try {
        $adcomputer = Get-ADComputer $Computer -Properties o, canonicalName
        $object.Division = [string] $adcomputer.o
        $object.CanonicalName = $adcomputer.CanonicalName
    }
    catch {
        $object.Division = 'Object Not Found'
        $object.CanonicalName = ' '
    }

    $object
}

$result | Export-Csv 'File Path' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Works beautifully. I must say that, from a personal visual standpoint, it bothers me that the '@{' has to be on the same line as '[PSCustomObject]'. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @RustyAndroid glad it helped. yeah PowerShell doesn't adapt very well to Allman coding style unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

[Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77991943/45375) offers an effective, streamlined solution.
Let me add **background information**:

- Unfortunately, the **cmdlets of the AD (Active Directory) provider exhibit *nonstandard behavior***:

  - They emit (statement-)*terminating* errors when they should be emitting *non-terminating* ones -  see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949027/45375) for background information on when which type of error should be reported.
  - As a result, applying the [common `-ErrorAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-erroraction) has *no* effect, as this parameter exclusively operates on non-terminating errors - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549569/45375) for background information.
  - Conversely, it is exclusively *terminating* errors that [`try { ... } catch { ... }`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) (and the rarely-used-anymore [`trap { ... }`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap)) statement act upon - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549569/45375) for background information.
  - Given the above, both for conceptual clarity and in the interest of future-proofing your code (however unlikely a fix to the error-reporting behavior is), it is **advisable to add  `-ErrorAction Stop` to *any* cmdlet call when intending to catch its (first) error via `try { ... } catch { ... }` (or `trap { ... }`)**.
- As for:

  ```
   # !! BROKEN, '@{' must be on the same line as [PSCustomObject]
   $NoComputer = [PSCustomObject]
   @{
      Name = $Computer
      Division = "Object Not Found"
      CanonicalName = " "
   }
  ```

  - PowerShell is a *hybrid* between a *shell* and a *traditional programming language*, which results in two distinct [parsing modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing) that are *situationally* applied:

    - *argument*-parsing mode, which acts like a traditional shell: single-line commands with whitespace-separated arguments that require *explicit line continuations* to straddle multiple lines, by placing `` ` `` (the so-called backtick, PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters)) at the *very end of a line*.
    - *expression*-parsing mode, which acts like a programming language: statements may straddle multiple lines, as long as the interior lines are *syntactically incomplete*.
    - However, given that PowerShell does *not* require explicit statement termination the way that C# does with `;` (though PowerShell *allows* statement *separation* with `;`), even in expression-parsing mode *ambiguities* can arise, as in the case at hand:

      - `$NoComputer = [PSCustomObject]` is *syntactically complete* (an assignment that receives a [*type literal*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65093924/45375)), and therefore forms a *statement of its own*, with the subsequent line starting a *new* statement.
      - In order for the subsequent lines' `@{ ... }` construct - which *in isolation* is a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) literal - to be considered part of a [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) literal, the previous line would either have to end in `` ` `` to signal line-continuation or - as is typical - for the `@{` part of the subsequent lines to start *on the previous line*.
    - Given the above, **it is a good habit to form to place an opening `@{` or `{` on the *same* line of (the start of the) statement that it forms a part of**.

      - Note: In so-called *language statements* ([keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Language_Keywords)-based statements such as `if`, `while`, and `foreach`) an opening `{` *can* be placed on a subsequent line, because such statements are *syntactically incomplete* without it; however, as the example at hand shows, it isn't always obvious when a line is or isn't syntactically complete, so said habit is still worth forming.
  - Because your code *didn't* do that, the intended [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) literal `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` inadvertently became *two* statements:

    - `$NoComputer = [PSCustomObject]`, i.e. the assignment of *type literal* `[PSCustomObject]` to variable `$NoComputer`...
    - ... followed by an independent [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) literal (`@{ ... }`) that was subject to *implicit output* - see the second section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375) for background information on PowerShell's implicit output behavior.
  - Because `$NoComputer` therefore didn't contain an object with the expected properties, [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) `-Append` failed with a (statement-terminating) error.

    - Note that `Export-Csv`'s behavior is always - whether with or without `-Append` - governed by the *first* input object, with the implicit assumption that all subsequent objects have the same structure.
    - With `-Append`, the first input object must have (at least) the same set of properties (columns) as the existing content (extra properties are ignored); the *order* of these properties does *not* matter, however.<sup>[1]</sup>

      - Because `$NoComputer` ended up (accidentally)  containing a `[System.Type]` instance rather than the intended `[pscustomobject]`, the expected properties weren't there.
    - As an aside: You can intentionally override the requirement that    properties for all existing columns be present by using the `-Force` switch, in which case *empty* column values are created for any (possibly all) of the preexisting properties (columns) that the input objects lack.

---

<sup>[1] Thus, an - inherently *unordered* - [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) is accepted too, as long as its entries match the existing columns *in any order*, but note that - fundamentally - `Export-Csv` only meaningfully accepts hashtable (dictionary) input in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).</sup>